# ¿Crear fichero txt en Android de manera publica?

Tags: java, android

Cómo utilizar correctamente getExternalStorageDirectory() para crear archivos de texto que puedan ser visualizados por el usuario. Independiente de si tengo una memoria externa o no.

Comment: En Android por motivos de seguridad cada aplicación dispone de un "espacio" reservado para almacenar sus datos y no se puede acceder desde otra aplicación, a no ser que guardes dicha información en la memoria externa. Para poder acceder a los datos almacenados por una aplicación en memoria interna necesitas ser root. Lo que se conoce vulgarmente como rootear el dispositivo.

Comment: Bienvenido Eduardo, visita la página [ask] para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta y sea bien recibida. Te doy un tip para guardar en memoria interna usa [getFilesDir()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+getFilesDir), pero si quieres sea "publico" en realidad el usuario necesitaría permisos de root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo dispositivo Android, cuenta con almacenamiento externo compartido, bien sea una memoria SD, o virtualizado. Basta con que uses el sistema de memoria externa para almacenar tus datos, un ejemplo podría ser:

```
try {
    File nuevaCarpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "CarpetaDePrueba");
if (!nuevaCarpeta.exists()) {
    nuevaCarpeta.mkdir();
}
try {
    File file = new File(nuevaCarpeta, "Archivo" + ".txt");
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("Error", "ex: " + ex);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Error", "e: " + e);
}
```

Sin olvidar los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: El OP desea guardar el archivo en "memoria interna" no en memoria externa.

Comment: El OP indica que quiere guardar un archivo visible para el usuario, lo cual ha de ser en la memoria externa, el indica lo siguiente `Tiene que ser en la memoria interna ya que el dispositivo en ningún momento contará con memoria Externa` lo cual es incorrecto, todo dispositivo Android cuenta con espacio externo compartido, véase un terminal sin tarjeta SD de almacenamiento, es emulada por Android, haciéndose accesible como si una externa física se tratase. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Porque no mejor aclarar que lo que pide no es lo que respondes, y que esto pudiera ser otra opción. Esto que agregas ya esta dentro del sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Comment: A mi punto de vista, lo que pregunta es lo que respondo, véase el titulo `¿Crear fichero txt en Android de manera publica?`, almacenar contenido en un lugar accesible, corrigiendo y aclarando que todo dispositivo dispone de un espacio externo, no obstante, si la respuesta no es propia, puede eliminarla sin problema, un saludo.

Comment: Justamente lo que respondió @Israel es la soloción que estaba buscando. Tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda, ya que con ella comprendi que aunque no tenga una tarjeta SD, siempre se podrá hacer uso de .getExternalStorageDirectory(). Ayer realicé pruebas y logré obtener el resultado deseado.