# ¿Como crear correctamente new File usando el path correcto?

Tags: java, android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El intentar crear un "FILE" en Android Studio con un path siempre me responde "**false**" al utilizar el metodo  myfile.exists().

¿Como puedo conseguir correctamente el path o Uri para crearlo? ya que lo agrego de diferentes maneras pero al parecer siempre resulta incorrecto.

Ejemplos:

```
 File myfile= new File(**myuri.toString()**);

 File myfile= new File("android.resource://myapps.me.test/drawable/pikachu");
```

**Con el formato del archivo**

```
File myfile= new File("android.resource://myapps.me.test/drawable/pikachu.png");
```

**Sin "drawable"**

```
File myfile= new File("android.resource://myapps.me.test/pikachu.png");
```

agradezco su apoyo de antemano.

Comment: Hola, te recomendaría usar un titulo mas sugerente para tu pregunta, poner un fragmento de código en el titulo lo hace difícil de leer y entender

Comment: Es importante comentar que requieres permisos pero es importante definir permisos manualmente para OS 6.0 o mayores, ademas recuerda que escribir en los recursos no es posible porque son de solo lectura. Agrego respuesta@Tuite

Comment: Tengo los persmisos en el Manisfest y tambien los solicito en la ejecución para las versiones mayores a la 19. Mi problema es que  no importa como cree el new File siempre la llamada me responde "no such file or directory". Mi problema es que no estoy pasando un file valido al RequestBody y no se como crearlo correctamaente ya que en la documentaicon solo dice que ocupo un path pero me doy cuenta que no se crea bien o me estoy saltando algun paso @Jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente es importante agregar el permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

pero para dispositivos mayores a 6.0 o mayor esta petición debe ser manual

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

usa este método:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

ahora es importante que sepas que no se puede crear un archivo en los recursos ya que son de solo lectura, por lo tanto esto es incorrecto.

```
File myfile= new File("android.resource://myapps.me.test/pikachu.png");
```

**No se puede crear un archivo en esta ruta.**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear ficheros en Android prácticamente de la misma manera que los haces en cualquier otra aplicación escrita en Java pasando la ruta, pero tienes que tener en cuenta el lugar donde lo quieres crear.

Para crear un fichero en el almacenamiento externo del dispositivo, tienes que solicitar los permisos en el manifest de la siguiente manera:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Y obtener la ruta de la carpeta externa con la función `getExternalFilesDir()`

Por el contrario, si el fichero lo quieres crear en el almacenamiento interno, de forma privada (que solo puede acceder a él la propia aplicación) no necesitas solicitar permisos y puedes usar la función `getFilesDir()` para obtener la ruta de la carpeta privada de la app.

En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/96785/77058) puedes ver un ejemplo.

Comment: Ya tengo eso permisos en el manifest y este archivo  lo utilizo para crear un RequestBody y finalmente usarlo en un Call con retrofit2. el problema es que siempre responde  la llamada "no file such or directory". Me di cuenta que puedes poner cualquier cosa en el path para crear el archivo y no encuentro alguna forma de validar si se creo correctamente o no.

Comment: @Tuite actualicé la respuesta con un enlace a un ejemplo

Comment: Agregue una imagen de lo que estoy haciendo y de como consigo el path de la imagen en la carpeta drawable. La verdad soy nuevo no se a que le puedo aplicar los metodos que me comentas para obtener el path.